# how to set a environment variables on some condition in github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

Below is my workflow in github:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2
```

How can I set variable value as per condition? Something like this

if `branch = master` then

```
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

else

```
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set env variables at the step level `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env` and use conditional at the step level as well `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`.

*You can find some information about the syntax [on the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions).*

Consequently, using the conditional to perform a specific step if the branch is master (or another branch) is possible.

Here is an example:

```
steps:

  name: Configure AWS credentials (MASTER)
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2

  name: Configure AWS credentials (NOT MASTER)
    if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/master'
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: eu-west-2
```

Here, the first step will only be executed if the branch is `master`, otherwise the second step will be executed.

Another reference can be found [on the github community](https://github.community/t/github-actions-branch-conditional/16057/3).